# PowerMock setInternalState for final field not working when using a getter

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, powermock, powermockito

I have a class like this.

```
public class ExampleClass {
    private final String finalString = "final";

    public String getFinalString() {
        return finalString;
    }
}
```

This is my sample test class which try to mutate the value of `finalString`

```
public class ExampleClassTest {
    private ExampleClass exampleClass = new ExampleClass();

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        Whitebox.setInternalState(exampleClass,"finalString","mocked");
    }

    @Test
    public void name() throws Exception {
        assertEquals("mocked", exampleClass.getFinalString()); //failing 
    }
}
```

But here, my assertion is failing. The value of `exampleClass.getFinalString()` is claimed to be `"final"`.

But when I debug the code at asserting line and check the value of the field `finalString` or when I try to get the value of the field `finalString` using reflections (code below), it shows the  `"mocked"` value.

My reflection code

```
Field finalStringField = exampleClass.getClass().getDeclaredField("finalString");
finalStringField.setAccessible(true);
assertEquals("mocked",finalStringField.get(exampleClass)); //passing
```

Anyone understands the trick here?

PS: my getter on the final field indeed looks weird. Please just ignore it.

And also, even if I add

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ExampleClass.class)
```

at top of my test class, same result

Comment: `@PrepareForTest(ExampleClass.class)` and `ExampleClass exampleClass = new ExampleClass();` are contradictory. Do you want to mock it or don't you? If you mock it, the mock won't have the field to use reflection on, so your test will fail. You need to use the real thing.

Comment: Also, you are using `setUp` in a weird way that does not make sense. Your test should include the test code itself and the assertion. Done this way, you can basically never add a 2nd test.

Comment: To repeat myself, and please read this very carefully: you cannot use reflection for a field on a mocked or proxy class (e.g. spy), because those classes will not have the field. Remove all mocking and all spies, and anything like that.

Comment: @Michael so my code doesn't include any mock or spy right. So is it okay if I just remove 2 annotations on the top to make things more clear?

Comment: You should do that, yes. I don't know the specifics of it, but the way PowerMock works when you do `PrepareForTest` is by fiddling with the class's bytecode when it's loaded by a classloader. So it's perfectly possible that reflection over that altered class might fail in some strange ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer my self. The correct way to fetch the value to assert is as follows. We need to make use of one of `Whitebox.getInternalState` or `Whitebox.getField` methods for that

So it will be one of the followings

`assertEquals("mocked", Whitebox.getInternalState(exampleClass,"finalString"));`

or

`assertEquals("mocked",Whitebox.getField(exampleClass.getClass(),"finalString").get(exampleClass));`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure which Whitebox you are using, you Should use the PowerMock one just update the line of Whitebox to

```
PowerMock.Whitebox.setInternalState(exampleClass, "finalString", "mocked");
```

, If above not working try to mock the object and call real method:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ExampleClass.class)
public class ExampleClassTest {

    private ExampleClass exampleClass;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        exampleClass = PowerMock.mock(ExampleClass.class, Mocktio.CALL_REAL_METHOD);
        PowerMock.Whitebox.setInternalState(exampleClass, "finalString", "mocked");
    }

    @Test
    public void name() throws Exception {
        assertEquals("mocked", exampleClass.getFinalString());
    }
}
```

Comment: the same result as my question

Comment: The first one, to check that use PowerMock.Whitebox one, not Mocktio.Whitebox.

Comment: yes but I forget the suffix, Is it end with `ito` or not

Comment: let me try at my local